# Any Framework dependencies on IIdentity.AuthenticationType?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I would like to leverage the `IIdentity.AuthenticationType` property in a custom FormsAuthentication scenario in order to set my own values. Using the out-of-the-box FormsAuthentication, the `AuthenticationType` of the `IIdentity` associated with the `HttpContext` is set to "Forms".

Could anyone verify if there is any logic in the core Asp.Net or Asp.Net MVC Frameworks that have functionality dependent upon the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Reflector, I analyzed all "Used By" dependencies of `IIdentity.AuthenticationType` and `FormsIdentity.AuthenticationType` and none of the core framework has any logic that is conditional to the `AuthenticationType` value.